# Connection problem to related_name in save_model function in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, signals

There is a model called `Borrow`. Inside `BorrowLine` model, a ForeignKey is defined with related_name `lines`. I write `BorrowAdmin` and `BorrowLineInline` for `Borrow` model. Inside `BorrowAdmin` class I used the `save_model` function as follows:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    print(obj.lines)
    return super(BorrowAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

But when I add an instance of `Borrow` model in Django administration, the following line is printed in the console:
`borrow.BorrowLine.None`
and I don't have access to any of the `BorrowLine` fields. For example, one of its fields is book, but when I call it, it gives this error:
`'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'book'`
How can I fix this problem and access the class fields?

my codes:

```
class Borrow(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('student.Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='borrow')
    created_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_time = models.DateField(default=date.today() + timedelta(days=7), validators=[delivery_time_validator])
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student)


class BorrowLine(models.Model):
    borrow = models.ForeignKey('Borrow', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lines')
    book = models.ForeignKey('book.Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lines')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.borrow} -> {self.book}'

    def clean(self):
        book = self.book
        if not book.is_available:
            raise ValidationError(f'The book {book.title} is not available.')
```

```
class BorrowLineInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BorrowLine
    extra = 1
    max_num = 3
    autocomplete_fields = ('book',)


@admin.register(Borrow)
class BorrowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BorrowLineInline,)
    list_display = ('student', 'created_time', 'delivery_time', 'delivered')
    search_fields = ('student__first_name', 'student__last_name', 'lines__book__title')
    list_filter = ('student__class_type', 'delivered', 'created_time', 'delivery_time')
    autocomplete_fields = ('student',)

    def add_view(self, request, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        self.fields = ('student', 'delivery_time')
        return super(BorrowAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        self.fields = ('student', 'delivery_time', 'delivered')
        return super(BorrowAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        print(obj.lines.book)
        # Do something
        return super(BorrowAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I also used signals like `post_save` and `pre_save` instead of `save_model`, but they also had the same error and returned None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manager always prints `app_name.ModelName.None`, you need to work with the `QuerySet`, so:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    print(obj.lines.all())
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

That being said, it will *not* show the `lines`, since it will first save the `obj` and then its many-to-many relations. You thus inspect the relation *after* saving the entire model:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    print(obj.lines.all())
```

If you want to process the `.book`s for these `lines`, you can work with:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    for line in obj.lines.select_related('book'):
        print(line.book)
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is only one problem. This for doesn't work when an instance of the model is being created, but it works when I change an already created instance. What should I do to make it work when a new instance is being created from this model?

Comment: @ArianNa: you need to work with the m2m relation *after* the `super()` call.